# how to split single data from string..?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, split, webclient

I would like to get single data from a string can any one help me to split the ID content alone. My Code that stores the Result value:

```
private void sendPostCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success..");
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
        string res=(string)e.Result;//here res contains my data..
        //need to get ID value alone.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you are getting a JSON string back. why don't you desieralize it to a class? it would be much easier than string parsing which is prone to errors etc... alternatively, do a split on the string by a common denominator and then find the id you are after, which appears to be on the last element - 2nd last - which will be the case when you split the string....

Comment: I'm new to WP8 if you provide me some example it would be helpful..

Comment: check out this [to autocreate your class for Json](http://json2csharp.com/) copy paste your json string (modify values if its private data).  Then take a look here how to [how-to-parse-json-in-c/serialize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)

Comment: Deserializing JSON is not specific to WP8. There are plenty of resources (including tutorials) around which will help you along. Try looking up JSON.Net (from Newtonsoft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem guys.. here is my sample code.. it works wel..

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);

int id=stuff.id;
```

Comment: Very kind of you to indicate your own answer as the correct one, while others tried  to help you...

Comment: it worked for me so i updated..

Comment: But you got your solution thanks to the people who helped you, not by yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Use [**json2csharp**](http://json2csharp.com/) to create a C# class for your JSON-string. Simplified example from your JSON:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
//You can make the id of type int if you want
```

Fastest way for working with JSON is using [**Json.NET**](http://json.codeplex.com/). Download the zip and use the dll from folder `Portable40`, this is the version that is compatible with Windows Phone 7. Reference the dll in your project and then your code should look similar to this:

```
string jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Qwer\", \"description\":\"\", \"timezone\":\"UTC\", \"id\":\"2912\"}";
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
int id = Convert.ToInt32(obj.id);
//value of id: 2912
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a class to deserialize into you could do something like this:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(e.Result);
string res= jsonObject["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably deserialize this into an object and then retrieve your values.

First create a class, with all your fields as parameters.

```
    class ResponseObject{
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public string Description{get;set;}
      ...
    }
```

and so on.

Then you can deserialize this response,

```
ResponseObject response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ResponseObject>(res);
```

Comment: A quick way to make your C# class is (in >=VS2012) `Edit>Paste Special>Paste JSON as classes`... obviously you need to copy it first.